# Ninject singleton init

Tags: .net, singleton, ninject

Im using Ninject 3.0.1.10 and I created a Ninject Module:

```vb
Public Class NinjectCustomModule
    Inherits NinjectModule

    Public Overrides Sub Load()
        'init
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now let's suppose I got an instance of Class A in my program and I pass it to the constructor of the module:

```vb
Public Class NinjectCustomModule
    Inherits NinjectModule

    Private _Obj As ClassA

    Public Sub New(ByVal Obj As ClassA)
        _Obj = Obj
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Load()
        'init
    End Sub


End Class
```

I know how to initialize a Singleton of Class A:

```
Bind(Of ClassA).ToSelf().InSingletonScope()
```

How to bind a Singleton of Class A **wich refer to the instance that I already have** (_Obj in my example)?

Also, what if ClassA is an **interface**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Bind(Of ClassA).ToConstant(instanceOfClassA)
```